# Hourly average data of CSV data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My data is in CSV format which is minute resolution. It looks like

```
Timestamp           value
6/10/2018 0:00       23.9
6/10/2018 0:01       19.8
6/10/2018 0:02       20.3
-------------------------
-------------------------
6/18/2018 23:59      25.9
```

Now I need the hourly average of this data. The code I have done so far is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.index = df['DateTime']
df1 = df.resample('H').mean()
print(df1)
```

But the output is not correct which is as

```
DateTime               Value
2018-06-13 00:00:00    16.19
2018-06-13 01:00:00    20.80
----------------------------
----------------------------
2018-12-06 23:00:00    19.09
```

The date is far from the actual data table. So please help me to debug it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data where the computed average value contradicts the actual data?

Comment: my data is from 2018-06-10 to 2018-06-18 but the computed values gives the average value from 2018-06-13 to 2018-12-06

Comment: What do you have in `df` just before resampling? I suspect conversion could mess things up. Similarly for indexing - the order of records could change. Then there is a matter if we need a moving average or average across hourly buckets....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` has trouble parsing your `Datetime` column, probably because the string representation begins with the month. I think `pandas` assumes it is day-first until it is no longer possible, then it goes month-first.

You should specify a format string :

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Conventions for string format are in this page :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: It should be your hour data that is the issue, as it is not zero-padded. Without the very data that you are using, it is hard to help you further.

Comment: just interchanged the format ='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' then only worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

instead this

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```